# MVC controller design of shopping cart

Tags: php, yii, shopping-cart

I am working on a cart page of an clothing website using PHP YII framework which is based on MVC architecture. Cart page has functionalities for updating size and quantity of the item in cart.

I can put two actions in `CartPageController`, one for updating size and other for updating quantity of an item or I can use only one action which takes a parameter, size or quantity, and then does the required operation.

Which would be better approach in terms of design?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd stick to one method. Both actions are, basically, *change* actions. So `change/quantity/4` and `change/size/M` can be treated in exactly the same way. There is something to be said for using one method per action but since the controller isn't the place to do *too* much processing of data, the controller method could look like this:

```
public function changeAction()
{
    $this->_model->change($arguments);//<-- let the Model-layer sort it out
}
```

As a rule of thumb: controllers are things that push data into models ASAP, the Model layer is where all the logic resides. Splitting the change actions into separate controller methods feels, to me at least, like the internal workings of your app are *"shifting"* to the controller